# on click en un selector distinto al que quiera

Tags: jquery

Debo ejecutar una función en JQuery cuando haga click en una clase distinta de "hola", es decir, cuando haga click en cualquier elemento que no tenga la clase "hola", ejecuto una función, algo como:

```
$(document).on("click touchend",!".hola", function(e){ ......});
```

Cómo podría hacerlo?

**EDIT**
Dejo el código para que vean qué error tengo, las clases que quiero clickear están dentro de tds:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(Principal);
    function Principal(){
    $(document).on("click", function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('hola')){
            console.log("clickeaste afuera"+$(this).attr("class"));
        }else{console.log("clickeaste adentro"+$(this).attr("class"))}

    });
    }
</script>

<body>
    <table>
    <tr><td class="sdha09001200hea">09:00 - 12:00</td><td>09:00 - 12:00</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="ashi10001330hod">10:00 - 13:30</td><td>10:00 - 13:00</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="hola">hola</td><td>holita</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el método `hasClass()`, un ejemplo:

```
$(event).on('click touchend', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('hola')) {
        // El elemento clickeado no tiene la clase hola
    }
    return false;
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').on('click', function (){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('hola')){
      alert('Este botón no tiene la clase hola')
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="hola" >HOLA</button>
<button type="button" class="adios" >ADIOS</button>
```

Comment: me reconoce la clase como "undefined", crearé un jsfiddle para que puedas ver si tengo algo mal

Comment: En mi respuesta te dejé un codesnippet, allí lo puedes probar e incluso copiar en un jsfiddle para que veas que funciona, aquí te lo dejo... [ https://jsfiddle.net/joriusrios/urv2g72k/ ]

Comment: gracias, mira, los elementos que estoy clickeando son td de una tabla, he probado a cambiar tus botones por tds y ahí deja de funcionar, cómo podría hacer que me encuentre la clase de la td?

Comment: revisa el edit por favor

Comment: Aquí te dejo otro jsfiddle para que pruebes, pues cambié el elemento `button` por `td` y funciona sin problemas, [ https://jsfiddle.net/joriusrios/4sv3caee/ ] revisa en que parte de tu código estás ejecutando este script, si si tienes cargado el jquery, etc...

Comment: Ahora sí, muchísimas gracias :D

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacer uso del selector [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) de jQuery para indicar que los eventos se deben aplicar a todos los elementos excepto los que tenga la clase `.hola`. Algo como esto:

```js
$("body").on("click touchend", ":not(.hola)", function(e){
  console.log("not hola");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="num1">1111</div>
<div class="hola">Hola</div>
<div class="num2">2222</div>
```

Comment: Algo como esto es lo que estaba buscando, pero lo probé en mi html y sigue sin funcionar, mis clases están dentro de tds, será por eso? y cómo podría solucionarlo? revisa el edit por favor.

Comment: Interesante. Sé que ya has encontrado una solución, pero voy a ver si puedo averiguar  por qué se salta el `:not`, por curiosidad.

Comment: genial, me lo haces saber cuando lo encuentres por favor